# Chrome Element Inspect

Tags: css

When debugging the CSS setting to an element, we can turn on the element inspect from Chrome Development Tool. Refer to below image, font-size, 14px is applied in style.css and which is override the setting from base.css, how about the `height`? There is no CSS declaration from any .css, which stylesheet is controlling the height?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the default `height:auto`. That means that by default height is set according to the height of content inside the element (80px in your case). And you can override it with css.

Answer (score 0):

The height of a block of text is a function of the `line-height` times the number of lines of text unless you set `display:block;`. So your height of 80px is just being ignored.

Note: Also, be careful when setting a fixed height for a text block because the text might become too long to fit in the box. You can use `overflow` to control what happens in that case.